# Why am I having this Socket Exception Errno=54?

Tags: flutter, sockets, http, get, socketexception

I am doing a very simple http get function by getting the time from worldtimeapi.org yet almost every time I get a SocketException: OS Error: Connection by peer, errno = 54, address = worldtimeapi.org = port = 57450)

```
Uri url = Uri.https('worldtimeapi.org','/api/timezone/Asia/Singapore', {'q': '{http}'});
var response = await http.get(url);
```

Comment: The URL doesn't seem to be working on `HTTPS`. `HTTP` seems to be working

Comment: The Error I got using uri.http() is StateError (Bad State: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/AsiaSingapore)

Comment: On which platform you're running this?